# Count characters of strings in a list and categorize into groups

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to compute a length histogram of a list (of strings) using Python 3?

The program would compute lengths of all elements, group elements having the same length and return the size of each group, paired with length of an element in that group.

For the following input list:

```
lis = [ "this" , "is" , "what" , "i" , "have" , "to" , "do" ]
```

The expected result is:

```
Letters per word:

3 with 4 letters
3 with 2 letters
1 with 1 letters
```

Is there a built-in container or function that facilitates this?

Comment: It isnt clear what your problem or question are right now, please try and reword what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#counter-objects) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(map(len, lis))
Counter({2: 3, 4: 3, 1: 1})
```

Comment: I love and hate this answer, because it's at once an awesome piece of Python and a copy-and-pastable answer to a question that should be closed.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I got the same mixed feeling after posting it, reading naltipar's comment and realising this. Maybe OP can still fix his question?

Comment: @arekolek It's probably fine, although it could stand some editing for clarity. Today, though; today, the help vampires won. :(

Comment: Beautifully written !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter` from collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which counts any hashable value in a iterable

```
>>> lis = [ "this" , "is" , "what" , "i" , "have" , "to" , "do" ]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count = Counter(len(x) for x in lis)
>>> for key in count:
    print(count[key], 'with', key, 'letters')


1 with 1 letters
3 with 2 letters
3 with 4 letters
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **`collections.defaultdict`**:

```
import sys
import collections

def processData(data):
    results = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for word in data:
        results[len(word)].append(word)
    return results

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    data = sys.argv[1:]
    print "Letters per word:\n"
    for k,v in dict(processData(data)).iteritems():
        print "{} with {} letters --> {}".format(len(v), k, ', '.join(v))
```

**Output:**

```
➜ python test.py stack overflow rocks
Letters per word:

1 with 8 letters --> overflow
2 with 5 letters --> stack, rocks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = [ "this" , "is" , "what" , "i" , "have" , "to" , "do" ]
a=[]
for item in lis:
    a.append(len(item)) 
b=set(a) 
print "Letters per words are :"
for item in b:
    k=a.count(item)
    print "%d with %d letters"%(k,item)
```